# Github pagination

Tags: javascript, algorithm, pagination

I wanted to copy the behavior of github's pagination. Here is what it turned out: http://jsbin.com/dihohiseca/5/edit?js,output

It works fine, but I have a feeling that there is a *lot* of room for improvements. Please help me make my code more elegant / shorter.

```js
var page = 12;
var numPages = 40;
var res = [];

var from = 1;
var to = numPages;
if (numPages > 10) {
  from = Math.max(page - 2, 1);
  to = Math.max(Math.min(page + 2, numPages), 5);
  if (to > 5) {
    res.push(1);
    if (from > 2) res.push(2);
    if (from > 3) {
      if (from === 4) {
        res.push(3);
      } else {
        res.push("...");
      }
    }
  }
}

for (var i = from; i <= to; i++) {

  res.push(i);

}

if (numPages > 10) {
  if (to < (numPages - 2)) {
    if (to === 8) {
      res.push(9);
    } else {
      res.push("...");
    }
  }
  if (to < numPages)
    res.push(numPages - 1);
  if (to !== numPages)
    res.push(numPages);
}

console.log(res);
$("body").html(res.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The part with bigger page number was easy,

```
var page = 7;
var numPages = 155;
// [1, 2, "...", 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "...", 154, 155]
//https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues?page=7&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed
```

but with page number 11 the code got very messy.

```
var page = 5;
var numPages = 11;
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, "...", 10, 11]
// https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues?page=7&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen


var page = 6;
var numPages = 11;
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
// https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues?page=6&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `page` and `numPages` are the only variables you actually get, and the code is a snippet inside some function (if not, put it in one!). So first is... your code is pretty much imperative. Nothing wrong with it but the usual "issues" I see is some really nested if statements and a bunch of variables for tracking purposes. We'll take care of that in a bit.

Next would be variable naming. `page` doesn't tell me much. Is it the current page? I think so. So name it `currentPage` instead. Same with the other variables. Name them to describe what they're supposed to do. `numPages`? How about `totalPages`? `res`... what's that?

Anyways, here's my take on your code in a less `if-else`-ish manner. It isolates the logic down to the very last moment, in the ternary. If I placed a breakpoint just before that, I can easily see my variables and infer from them what happens next. Compare that to a deep `if-else` code where you have to step through the code in order to know how it ran, which branch it took this time etc.

```js
function range(n){
  return Array.apply(null, Array(n)).map(function (_, i) {return i;});
}

function generatePagination(currentPage, totalPages){

  // First we move out the configurations. That way, they don't mingle with the logic.
  var initialChunkPadding = 1;
  var middleChunkPadding = 2;
  var endingChunkPadding = 1;
  var gapValue = '...';

  // Instead of a loop, we use range. It's much cleaner and we don't have tracking variables
  // at the cost of generating an array.
  return range(totalPages).reduce(function(pagination, index){

    // Then we determine what the current page is based on some comparisons
    var page = index + 1;
    var isInitialChunk = page <= 1 + initialChunkPadding;
    var isMiddleChunk = page >= currentPage - middleChunkPadding && page <= currentPage + middleChunkPadding;
    var isEndingChunk = page >= totalPages - endingChunkPadding;
    var hasNoGap = pagination[pagination.length - 1] !== gapValue;

    // Then based on the determinations, we determine what value gets pushed into the array.
    // It can either be the page, a '...', or a blank array (which doesn't change anything with concat)
    var valueToAdd = isInitialChunk || isMiddleChunk || isEndingChunk ? page : hasNoGap ? gapValue : [];
    
    return pagination.concat(valueToAdd);
  }, []);
}

// StackExchange should seriously add a console view >.<
document.write(JSON.stringify(generatePagination(16, 40)));
document.write('<br>');
document.write(JSON.stringify(generatePagination(7, 155)));
document.write('<br>');
document.write(JSON.stringify(generatePagination(5, 11)));
document.write('<br>');
document.write(JSON.stringify(generatePagination(6, 11)));
```

Comment: excellent solution and explanation, but I found a tiny mistake. generatePagination(1, 21) results: [1,2,3,"...",20,21], instead of [1,2,3,4,5,"...",20,21] .

Comment: And generatePagination(20, 21) results [1,2,"...",19,20,21] which should be [1,2,"...", 17, 18,19,20,21]  see :https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues?page=21&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen (this is a bug in my code too)

Comment: @user3568719 Ahh, yep. That's a bug. The nice thing though is that the `reduce` is running through all page numbers. You can simply add a condition (I guess 2, one for the starting 5, and ending 5), and include them in the ternary that adds the page.